# HOWTO Fluent Bit OUTPUT to multiple Kinesis Firehose on multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose, fluent-bit, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to send same logs to multiple Kinesis Firehose Stream on multiple AWS account via Fluent Bit v1.8.12. How can I use the `role_arn` in [kinesis_firehose OUTPUT](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/firehose) property correctly? I'm able to send to firehose A but not firehose B. Also, role A on AWS A can assume role B on AWS account B.
This is what I'm trying to do

[image: schema]

This is fluent bit OUTPUT conf

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name              kinesis_firehose
    Match             aaa
    region            eu-west-1
    delivery_stream   a
    time_key          time  
    role_arn          arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/role-a

# THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK
[OUTPUT]
    Name              kinesis_firehose
    Match             bbb
    region            eu-west-1
    delivery_stream   b
    time_key          time  
    role_arn          arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/role-b
```

fluent bit pod logs says:

```
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [error] [aws_credentials] STS assume role request failed
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [ warn] [aws_credentials] No cached credentials are available and a credential refresh is already in progress. The currentco-routine will retry.
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [error] [signv4] Provider returned no credentials, service=firehose
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [error] [aws_client] could not sign request
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [error] [output:kinesis_firehose:kinesis_firehose.1] Failed to send log records to b
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [error] [output:kinesis_firehose:kinesis_firehose.1] Failed to send log records
[2022/06/21 15:03:12] [error] [output:kinesis_firehose:kinesis_firehose.1] Failed to send records
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't know which role the fluent-bit pod was assuming. Enablind fluent-bit debug logs helped me.

It appears that fluent-bit assumes a particular `role x` that includes many EKS policies. I added to this role a policy that let this `role x` assume both roles `role a` (can write to Kinesis in account AWS A) and `role b` (can write to Kinesis in account AWS B). No changes were made to fluent bit configuration.

The solution is painted below:
[image]