# EKS fluent-bit unable to assume AWS role from service account

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis-firehose, fluent-bit

I'm going mad over a fluent bit DaemonSet installed via Helm in EKS on Account AWS yyyyyyy unable to send data to Kinesis in AWS account xxxxxxxxxx.

It looks like EKS does not have OIDC provider on IAM but it's false! Can you help?

**fluent bit logs**:

```
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [output:kinesis_firehose:kinesis_firehose.0] firehose:PutRecordBatch: events=157, payload=71245 bytes
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [output:kinesis_firehose:kinesis_firehose.0] Sending log records to delivery stream kinesis_backend
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Requesting credentials from the EC2 provider..
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] inode=19100461 events: IN_MODIFY 
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [input chunk] update output instances with new chunk size diff=693
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] inode=19100461 events: IN_MODIFY 
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [http_client] server firehose.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 will close connection #74
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_client] firehose.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: http_do=0, HTTP Status: 400
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [error] [aws_client] auth error, refreshing creds
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Refresh called on the env provider
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Refresh called on the profile provider
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Reading shared config file.
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Shared config file /root/.aws/config does not exist
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Reading shared credentials file.
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [error] [aws_credentials] Shared credentials file /root/.aws/credentials does not exist
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Refresh called on the EKS provider
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] Calling STS..
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [http_client] server sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 will close connection #74
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_client] sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: http_do=0, HTTP Status: 400
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_client] Unable to parse API response- response is not valid JSON.
[2022/06/29 15:22:34] [debug] [aws_credentials] STS raw response: 
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidIdentityToken</Code>
    <Message>No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for https://oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>c517249d-c018-43c3-a712-d0e5080ded86</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

**fluent-bit service account** in namespace newrelic (created by fluentbit Helm chart)

```
kubectl -n newrelic describe sa fluent-bit
Name:                fluent-bit
Namespace:           newrelic
Labels:              app.kubernetes.io/instance=fluent-bit
                     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                     app.kubernetes.io/name=fluent-bit
                     app.kubernetes.io/version=1.9.4
                     helm.sh/chart=fluent-bit-0.20.2
Annotations:         eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/kinesis-write
                     meta.helm.sh/release-name: fluent-bit
                     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: newrelic
```

**Policy permissions** attached to role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/kinesis-write

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "firehose:PutRecord",
                "firehose:PutRecordBatch"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:firehose:region:xxxxxxxxxx:deliverystream/kinesis-backend"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/kinesis-write trusted relationships** (I included OIDC Provider for my EKS cluster on account yyyyyyyyyy)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::yyyyyyyyy:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:sub": "system:serviceaccount:newrelic:fluent-bit"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72703582/2519150. The same solution can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool, because I had to debug similar issues. You can try it - https://github.com/pete911/kubectl-iam4sa
It will print cloud trail events as well when you run `kubectl-iam4sa get -n newrelic fluent-bit`. It could be that you are missing some permissions ... Or you can just try to search cloudtrail by `username: system:serviceaccount:newrelic:fluent-bit`